# Oracle SQL Developer and Toad Excel export not updating during export process

Tags: excel, oracle, export, toad

I have a problem exporting a large number of records in any specific table from an oracle 11g database using both sql developer and toad.  I'm running Windows 7 on a brand new laptop.  Specs:

[image]

When right click in my results pane after running a query and select export to excel (this process is only slightly different between developer and toad), the file starts the export process; however when I check the actual file in the specified directory, it is not updating in size.  So for example the query I in Toad just ran was exporting approx. 1.2 million records but at around 600,000 it locked and gave me these error messages:

[image]

Oracle did the same thing after approx. 400,000 records, except no error message - it just crashed.  So we ran the same query on my partners laptop which is the same make and model with the exact same specs and it exported in about 60 seconds.  We noticed that in the file explorer directory where the file was being written, the size kept going up as the export process was running. Every time we refreshed the file explorer window, the size of the file be written increased during the entire export process.  Is this a setting in Oracle/Toad or is it a windows issue?

Comment: This is not really a programming question.  Maybe post to TOAD support?

Comment: Well not really as I have stated, that it does it in both Toad and SQL Developer.